# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \mu(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_n)$

Tags: measure-theory

Here is the **full question**:

> Let $(X, \mathfrak{U},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $E_k$ be
>   measurable sets s.t. $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k) \lt \infty$. Define:
>
> $$A_n = \{x \in X : x \in E_k \text{ for exactly $n$ values of $k$}\}$$
>   $$B_n = \{x \in X : x \in E_k \text{ for at least $n$ values of $k$}\}$$
>
> Show that the sets $A_n, B_n$ are measurable and
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \mu(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \mu(E_n)$$

**Partial solution:**

The measurability part was no problem. (Both $A_n$ and $B_n$ can be written as countable unions of countable intersections).

For the first equality $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \mu(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_n)$, I used the fact $B_n=B_{n+1} \cup A_n$ and that it is a disjoint union (take measures of both sides then multiply by $n$...).

I can't figure out how to approach the second equality, there is no obvious identity i can use.

**ADDED:** The proof should use nothing more than simple theorems and definitions of $\sigma$-algebras algebras semi rings and measures. (In particular no integrals).

Comment: Consider $$f = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \chi_{E_k}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, but i still don't see it...

Comment: Sorry, without integrals it's not nearly as straightforward. I'm deleting my answer until I have time to think about it properly after dinner.

Comment: Not so incredibly nice what I came up with. But well, it works.

Comment: You can avoid Borel–Cantelli by proving $\sum_{k=1}^m \mu(E_k) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(B_n)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^m \mu(B_k) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n)$ for all $m$, but it still seems to boil down to rearranging sums of measures of "atomic" sets analogous to the $G_K$s defined by Daniel Fischer in his answer. As far as I can tell, that's not any simpler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We define

$$f = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \chi_{E_k}.$$

Since the $E_k$ are measurable, their characteristic functions are measurable, and hence so is $f$. Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k) < \infty$, $f$ is integrable, and hence $f^{-1}(\infty)$ is a null set.

Then we have

$$A_n = f^{-1}(\{n\}),\quad B_n = f^{-1}([n,+\infty))$$

which shows these sets are measurable, and

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k) = \int_X f\,d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{A_n} f\,d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mu(A_n)$$

by - for example - the monotone convergence theorem.

Further, we have

$$f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{B_n}$$

which implies

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k) = \int_X f\,d\mu = \int_X \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{B_n}\,d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(B_n).$$

Note that if $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty B_n$, the set of points lying in infinitely many $E_k$, has positive measure, then we still have the equality $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mu(B_n)$, both are $+\infty$ then, but it can be that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mu(A_n) < +\infty$ in that case.

---

Without integrals, it is not as straightforward.

I hoped to avoid it, but I don't see a nice direct way without some construction of the following sort.

First we note that the set of points lying in infinitely many $E_k$ is a null set. If available, that's an application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, otherwise we prove it here.

$$N := \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k\right)$$

is the set of points lying in infinitely many $E_k$. And since for all $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ we have

$$\mu(N) \leqslant \mu \left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k\right) \leqslant \sum_{k=n}^\infty \mu(E_k)$$

by the montonicity and $\sigma$-subadditivity of $\mu$, the finiteness of $\sum \mu(E_k)$ implies $\mu(N) = 0$. By replacing all $E_k$ with $E_k\setminus N$, all the measures remain unchanged, hence we may assume $N = \varnothing$.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the set of nonempty finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, and for $K \in\mathcal{P}$, we define

$$F_K = \bigcap_{k\in K} E_k$$

and

$$G_K = F_K \setminus \bigcup_{k\notin K} E_k.$$

Since $\mathcal{P}$ is countable, the $F_K$ and $G_K$ are measurable. Also $G_{K} \cap G_M = \varnothing$ for $K\neq M$, and

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k = \bigcup_{K\in \mathcal{P}} G_K.$$

Further we have

$$A_n = \bigcup_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\ \operatorname{card} K = n}} G_K,\qquad B_n = \bigcup_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\ \operatorname{card} K \geqslant n}} G_K,$$

which shows that $A_n$ and $B_n$ are countable unions of measurable sets, hence measurable.

Next, for every $k$ we have

$$E_k = \bigcup_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\ k\in K}} G_K$$

and therefore

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu\left(\bigcup_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\ k\in K}} G_K\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\ k\in K}}\mu(G_K)\\
&= \sum_{K\in\mathcal{P}}\sum_{k\in K} \mu(G_K)\\
&= \sum_{K\in\mathcal{P}} \operatorname{card} K\cdot \mu(G_K)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\\operatorname{card} K = n}} n\cdot \mu(G_K)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\sum_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\\operatorname{card} K = n}} \cdot \mu(G_K)\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \mu\left(\bigcup_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\ \operatorname{card} K = n}} G_K\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mu(A_n).
\end{align}

And finally

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(B_n) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\left(\bigcup_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\ \operatorname{card} K \geqslant n}} G_K\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\ \operatorname{card} K \geqslant n}}\mu(G_K)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty \sum_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\\operatorname{card} K = k}}\mu(G_K)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^k \sum_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\\operatorname{card} K = k}}\mu(G_K)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot \sum_{\substack{K\in\mathcal{P}\\\operatorname{card} K = k}}\mu(G_K)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot \mu(A_k).
\end{align}

Unless I'm overlooking something very simple, this exercise can serve as a good illustration of the power of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Thanks! looks marvelous, but i'm afraid it uses things that aren't yet introduced in the book. The only concepts i'm expected to use are the definitions and basic theorems about measures semi-rings algebras and $\sigma-$algebras.

Comment: Well, it is different. Shows the power of integrals.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thank you for the nice solution(s). In this question, it is assumed that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(E_k)<\infty$. This is required in your second proof (to ensure that the set of points in the intersection of the $E_k$ is a null-set). However, it seems to me that in the proof using Lebesgue integration the assumption is not needed, with the understanding that if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(E_k)=\infty$, then all three terms are infinite. Do you agree, or did I overlook something in the measure-theoretic proof?

Comment: @Ian No, that is also used in the integral version, I just haven't made it explicit (which I should have done and will), if the set of points appearing in infinitely many $E_k$ has positive measure, then it can be that $\sum n\mu(A_n) < \infty$ and the equality doesn't hold (the equality $\sum \mu(E_k) = \sum \mu(B_n)$ also holds in that case), for then $f$ is infinite on a set of positive measure. The premise $\sum \mu(E_k) < \infty$ asserts that $f$ is integrable, hence can be infinite only on a null set.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks a lot for the thorough answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer I added a bounty for hope of finding a simpler proof. If no one finds it i'll grant the bounty to you.

Comment: @user116395 There is no simpler proof.  Any proof simpler than that will simply skip some of the details of the proof given above.  This is also a testament to why we always say 'functions over sets' and 'integrals over measures'.  More flexibility, more tools, less need to count.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think you mean: _"but it can't be that..."_ at the end of the integrals solution.

Comment: @leo No, I mean "it can be". Consider the simplest case, $E_1 = E_2 = \dotsc$, all $E_k$ being equal (and not a null set). Then you have $\sum \mu(E_k) = \sum \mu(B_n) = +\infty > 0 = \sum n\cdot \mu(A_n)$. The equality $\sum \mu(E_k) = \sum \mu(B_n)$ is true without any finiteness assumption, but $\sum n\cdot \mu(A_n)$ can be finite if $\sum \mu(E_k) = +\infty$.

Comment: Yes, the triple equality doesn't holds in general. I misread the thing, wanted that _can_ to be some other _can't_. Thank you for the clarification.